# set random color to a textbox from a set of colors in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am using a string array for indexing colors.

```
string[] fore {"Colors.Yellow","Colors.Red","Colors.Blue","Colors.White","Colors.Green"};
int sIndex = rnd.Next(fore.Length);
textblock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(fore[sIndex]);
```

But it gives an invalid argument error?
What to do ?

Comment: Instead of an array of string, make an array of color and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting in a string in the SolidColorBrush Constructor. I think it needs a Color object. Try make a Color[] instead of a string array:

```
     Color[] fore=  {Color.Yellow,Color.Red,Color.Blue,Color.White,Color.Green };
     int sIndex = rnd.Next(fore.Length);
     textblock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(fore[sIndex]);
```

Comment: it did'nt solve! i guess  Color is for describing colours in alpha,red,green,blue channels...

Comment: Not really.  System.Windows.Media.Color is a class which has static properties for many colors. The constructor for SolidBrushColor takes one of those as a parameter. Maybe you are using System.Drawing.Color, don;t know if that makes any difference. But what is the error with the above code??

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Color does not contain a definition for yellow or red

Comment: @VarunBehl Ok nice to hear! You could mark my answer as accepted if it helped you. This also helps other with the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

*Well*, since `fore[sIndex]` is a `string`, looks like [`SolidColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have a constructor takes `string` as a parameter. But [it has a constructor that takes `Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558629%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a parameter.

You can change it to `Color` array instead of `string` array.

```
Color[] fore = new[] { Color.Yellow, Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.White, Color.Green };
int sIndex = rnd.Next(fore.Length);
textblock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(fore[sIndex]);
```

Comment: it says cant convert from System.Windows.Media.Color[] to System.Windows.Media.Colors[]  at new operator!! and thus doesn't work ? Though Colors is for predefined colors only..

Comment: @VarunBehl That's weird. There is no constructor of `SolidColorBrush` that tales `Colors` as a parameter.